# Circular Motion, Vectors and Elasticity

Tags: physics

[image]

**My Doubts:**
Elastic modulus should be in $N/m^2$ but here it is in Newtons only is this correct or they just mean here $k=30 N/m$ ? What do you want to say about $\lambda = 30 N$ ?

Do you think my equations are correct to solve for correct answer

**My Try:**

Let $x$ be the elongation, so we have
$$T\cos\theta=mg$$
$$T\sin\theta=m\omega^2 r \;\;\;,\;\;\;r=(l+x)\sin\theta$$
$$T=kx$$

Using these three equations I can solve for $\theta\;\;,\;\; T$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: very good that you wrote $r=l+x \sin \theta$ , if it was me , I'd have completely missed that lol. However, the equations look ok to me.

Comment: thanks , i just want to know about lambda i think it is not standard notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the author [defines](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/pasp/Young_s_Modulus_Spring_Constant.html) **elastic modulus** here as $$\frac{\text{tension in the string}}{\text{relative extension}}\\=\text{tension in string}\times\frac{\text{original length}}{\text{elongation}},$$ which has units Newtons.

This replaces your third equation; everything else looks fine.

Comment: not sure if that is the definition, have you seen such definitions in the books ? If yes then it really replaces the third equation, thanks

Comment: yes i clicked that , let me check this one too

Comment: amazing this confirms.... thank you